# How do the Mythic Lockouts work in World of Warcraft with cross realm progression?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With cross realm progression being released, how do the mythic raid lock outs work for Uldir? Can someone with the same lockout join another persons lock out?

For example, if I am 2/8 can I join a guild who is also 2/8M?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that.

If you started a raid with a group you have exactly that ID and cannot join another group with the same bosses (or any other number greater than 0) on a different lockout ID.

Your group can even kill bosses without you and you'll find them dead if you go there at a later time.

If you're quick enough or your first group didn't continue their ID you can do so with a new group. However, they *all* have to have no ID on Uldir Mythic or they will face your problem again.